# Error $.getJSON - Jquery -

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

When consuming a json using $.getJSON ..

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(obj){
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
      $.each(value, function(keys, values){
        console.log(values.title);
      });
    });
});
```

The following error occurs:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

**Note: When the same code is entered directly into the console, the data is normally listed**

Comment: Can you post your json file contents to pastebin or something for more details?

Comment: Are you sure the error come from this? Did you checked at the line number?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code you posted - the error must be due to code you have not posted

Comment: The file has just this:

       $ (Document) .ready (function () {
         // List all
        $ .getJSON ('data.json', function (obj) {
             $ .each (obj, function (key, value) {
             $ .each (value, function (keys, values) {
             Console.log (values.title);
             });
             });
         });
});

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my json data that i have stored in a file named book.json

```
[{"book":[{"title":"Book1"},{"title":"Book2"}]},{"book":[{"title":"Book3"},{"title":"Book4"}]}]
```

then within my js file i have added the following script-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('book.json', function(obj){
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
      $.each(value.book, function(keys, values){
        console.log(values.title);
      });
    });
   });
});
```

It is working for me.

Comment: Actually the problem was not in the code mentioned.
It was a problem with the formatting of the characters, I saved it for another IDE. And the problem was normalized.